# Link axes callback for subplots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have multiple subplots going on, some are time series some are histograms. For example:

```
figure;
subplot(2, 2, 1);
% Lets same time series goes from time 0 to 100 seconds (the x component)
plot(time_series_data_x, time_series_data_y)
subplot(2, 2, 2);
histogram(some_histogram_data);
subplot(2, 2, 3);
plot(another_time_series_data_x, another_time_series_data_y);
subplot(2, 2, 4);
plot(another_histogram_data);
% If user zooms or pans on one time series we want the other time series to
% also pan/zoom
linkaxes([subplot(2, 2, 1), subplot(2, 2, 3)], 'x');
```

What I would like to do is:

- user zooms in on a time series, lets say now X goes from 20-30
  seconds
- Callback somehow
- Get the xlimits of the plot (20-30 seconds)
- Update the histogram plots so now the histogram plots only show from time 20-30 seconds (done in the callback)

I have many different types of subplots (images, polar plots), which is why I would prefer a callback approach. This way I can do any modifications to data displayed needed.

Comment: Here's an FYI that will prove useful. You can save the object handles of the subplots to variables, say: `hist_1 = subplot(2,2,2)`. To add features like the axes display adjustment I would add slider objects (using `uicontrol`) somewhere on the figure. The slider's `callback` can be fed the object handles of different axes on which you're plotting. So you could have two sliders (one for panning along x, and another for panning along y). The slider's `callback` should be fed the handles of all your axes so that then you update the `xlim` and `ylim` of all axes using the `set` function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question intrigued me a lot. I wasn't able to figure it out using conventional `uicontrol` objects so I did some digging. It turns out that the panning and zooming features can be saved as handles to variables in a script (truly fascinating, Mathworks please never nerf). There are dedicated `pan` and `zoom` objects which feature `callbacks`, however, they do not go by the name 'callback'. Both the `zoom` and `pan` objects feature a property called `ActionPostCallback`, which acts like a `callback` to a user-defined `function`. The way it works is that whenever the user is done panning or zooming in or out of an `axes` object, that `function` is called. In said `function` you can pass the handles to the other interactive objects so that they update accordingly.

To exemplify this, I provide below a programmatically made GUI:

```
clc
clear
close all
f = figure; %Figure "Parent" object.

xoff = 0.1; %Spacing between axes in the x-direction.
yoff = 0.1; %Spacing between axes in the y-direction.
xw = 0.35; %x-width of the axes.
yw = 0.35; %y-width of the axes.

%First set of axes
ax1 = axes('Parent',f,'units','normalized','position',...
    [xoff,yoff,xw,yw],'box','on');
xlabel(ax1,'ax1 X-limits')
ylabel(ax1,'ax1 Y-limits')

%Second set of axes
ax2 = axes('Parent',f,'units','normalized','position',...
    [xoff,2*yoff+yw,xw,yw],'box','on');
xlabel(ax2,'ax2 X-limits')
ylabel(ax2,'ax2 Y-limits')

%Third set of axes
ax3 = axes('Parent',f,'units','normalized','position',...
    [2*xoff+xw,yoff,xw,yw],'box','on');
xlabel(ax3,'ax3 X-limits')
ylabel(ax3,'ax3 Y-limits')

%Fourth set of axes
ax4 = axes('Parent',f,'units','normalized','position',...
    [2*xoff+xw,2*yoff+yw,xw,yw],'box','on','ButtonDownFcn',{@printstuff});
xlabel(ax4,'ax4 X-limits')
ylabel(ax4,'ax4 Y-limits')

%Panning Object Handle.
P = pan(f); %Handle that references the pan icon (the hand thingy)
P.ActionPostCallback = {@adjust,ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4};
P.Enable = 'on';

%Zooming Object Handle
Z = zoom(f); %Handle that references the zoom in/out buttons.
Z.ActionPostCallback = {@adjust,ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4};
Z.Enable = 'on';

%Axes limit adjusting function.
function adjust(~,ax_ref,ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4)
%Obtain the x and y limits of the axes just referenced.
newxlim = get(ax_ref.Axes,'Xlim');
newylim = get(ax_ref.Axes,'Ylim');
%Update x-limits
set(ax1,'Xlim',newxlim)
set(ax2,'Xlim',newxlim)
set(ax3,'Xlim',newxlim)
set(ax4,'Xlim',newxlim)
%Update y-limits
set(ax1,'Ylim',newylim)
set(ax2,'Ylim',newylim)
set(ax3,'Ylim',newylim)
set(ax4,'Ylim',newylim)
end
```

Running this script should produce the following:
[image]

If you pan or zoom, the x and y limits adjust on all `axes` objects. This is achieved by the above `function` called "adjust." In the lines where `ActionPostCallback = {@adjust,ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4}` is present, I'm simply passing the handles to the four (4) axes that I hardcoded. You can do the same with your `subplots`. As you may known, when executing a `callback` to a `function`, the function's first two (2) arguments pertain to the objects that initiate the `callback`. For me, the first argument linked to the figure object `f`, whereas the second (that `ax_ref` input in the `function`) linked to the actual `axes` that I panned or zoomed into. From that second argument, I just use `set` and `get` to enable the updates. This should satisfy your needs if you "preplot" the data (i.e., the data rendering from calling `hist` is done before the `pan` and `zoom` objects are defined).

**NOTE**: If you use the above GUI for your project, make sure that in the `hist`, `plot`, or any other data visualization commands you explicitly define which axes to plot to. I hardcoded the axes because I was exploring using slider objects (which are `uicontrol` objects)

Hope this helps mate.